# How to change AppiumDriver focus to dropdown that appears on a different layer? iOS

Tags: ios, iphone, selenium, appium

I'm using Appium and I don't face this issue on Android. Only on iOS.

The app is made on React Native. Some sections of the app use a dropdown that when you tap on them, show some options but hide the rest of the app behind a shadow. Something similar to this:

[image: https://www.oreilly.com/library/view/react-native-cookbook/9781491993835/assets/rncb_0102.png]

When this happens, the focus of the `AppiumDriver` remains on the background, so I can't tap/click on the options or any of the elements that appear on the front. Similar in some way to what happens when you're using Selenium `WebDriver` and a new popup appears and you have to change the focus of the driver in order to interact with its elements.

I've tried with `"getWindowsHandles()"` or `"getContextHandles()"` but it doesn't work for this scenario.

The only thing that worked to click these options was using X,Y coordinates which is not very optimal, so I'm aiming to find a better solution in which I can interact with these elements setting the `AppiumDriver` focus on the options.

Comment: Could you check if Appium inspector can see elements in your dropdown list?

Comment: That's what I'll try to do next. The thing is that I don't have a Mac here so I will have to use a virtual machine.

Comment: So far, I couldn't make it work. The app I inspect is the app deployed for Simulator. There, with Appium explorer I can see how to catch the element. But the execution on the real application and appium is different. For some reason it doesn't focus on the dropdown options I need to tap on and if I call a driver.getPageSource() it retrieves the source code of the background.
I still have some hope to make it work the right way but I also think I might have to workaround with a tapOnXY() method.

Answer (score 0):

You can try locating it using the Accessibility Id in your code (not in Appium Inspector). The Accessibility Id will be similar to the text of the option like
`accessibility id = "Reload"`